# Saving images as ALAssets without duplicates

Tags: duplicates, alassetslibrary, alasset

I'd like to download images with the dropbox api and save them in a custom album ("DropBox") in my ALAssetLibrary.
However I don't want to save duplicates. So what is the best way to check if the image is already present in the album.
Is there some sort of hashing within the ALAssetLibrary which I can utilize for this purpose?
I don't mind hashing the NSData of my download images, but doing this for all the images in the album would be way to much.
Maybe storing hashes in meta data someway?

Thank you very much!

akw

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works for me so far:

I "misuse" the EXIF user comment tag to save a hash value (in my case, just the dropbox path).

After downloading an image from DropBox, I save it with `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum` and store the DropBox path of the image in the `kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment`.

This way, I only need to scan the ALAssetsGroup for these tags and if present I do not need to download the image at all. Works fine.